# Bulk API v1 using SOAP protocol

Tags: bulk-api

I need to import data in bulk using SOAP API (due to a limitation on client's middleware).

Bulk API v2 - based on REST. Is Bulk API v1 also REST? Can I use v1 with SOAP protocol?

[Bulk API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_intro.htm)

> Bulk API is based on REST principles and is optimized for loading or
> deleting large sets of data. You can use it to query, queryAll,
> insert, update, upsert, or delete many records asynchronously by
> submitting batches. Salesforce processes batches in the background.
>
> SOAP API, in contrast, is optimized for real-time client applications
> that update a few records at a time. You can use SOAP API for
> processing many records, but when the data sets contain hundreds of
> thousands of records, SOAP API is less practical. Bulk API is designed
> to make it simple to process data from a few thousand to millions of
> records.

Comment: As the given the Salesforce documentation shared in your question, Bulk API v1 is also based on REST. You can't use v1 with SOAP but for login you would need to use SOAP API (when using Bulk API v1). What the volume of data you need to load? If its a one time load you are planning to do, ask for 'why does it necessarily need to go thru the middleware'?

Comment: @arut Thank you very much for your insight. It is a repeating integration around 100k records. But if I log in using SOAP, can I get send the request in an XML format and simulate a SOAP call? Probably not, right?

Comment: SOAP login is used in Bulk API (v1) only to fetch the token or session information (and rest of the callouts will be via Bulk API/ REST principle). So, the answer to your question is 'No'. However, the documentation is really pointing towards using SOAP API for everything including data upload but with smaller payloads. Having a middleware that supports SOAP only and handling large data volumes is challenging.

Comment: @arut First of all thank you, second of all you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We switched from Bulk API to SOAP API with 200 records per call. Bulk API v1 uses SOAP login, but otherwise is based on REST, not SOAP.